# To get list of class name, list of methods variables etc from a source file using eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Hi All 
Am new to eclipse plugin development. In fact never wrote one.
I want to develope a plugin a plugin , before that just want to make sure whether its possible to implement below said features.
I should have a ui buton/interface when clicked **should get me the the list of class, methods variables present in the active source file(.java)**.And I should be able to compare these class variable or methods name agains some other strings etc ....Also I need to **print somethimg based one these comparision on to console.**
Is it possible to do it?Is possible to get list of methods classes and varibales from a source file?Please help
Also is the same possible for C CPP source files?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Meteorite

Comment: It is definitely possible for Java and although I haven't tried it with C/CPP, I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible with them.

Answer (score 0):

IMO all the needs you described in your question can be addressed within an Eclipse plug-in.

To access a java file structure you can use the JDT abstract syntax tree model. A nice blog about how to use the AST : http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html

You could do the same for C/C++ using the CDT, but I have been told that the API is a bit more complicated to use.

To add a button in the UI I suggest you to read the following article: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html

For the console output it is here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F

You will need to do the comparison logic yourself but it should not be a problem.